# Microsoft GraphEngine LIKQ query

Tags: .net, algorithm, graph, graphengine

### Description

I have a simple directed graph which has two end nodes C,E (sinks) and one starting node A. The Framework i am using is Microsoft's [GraphEngine](https://www.graphengine.io/).

[image: GraphGeneration]

My TSL File looks like this: A graph node consists of an *NodeItem* which is just an container with a property *Id* and *Name*. The node has *OutEdges* for outgoing relations and *InEdges* for incoming releations.

[image: TSL File]

I know that there are several graph algorithms like A*, Dijkstra, Floyd Warshall, Bellman–Ford, etc. ... Each of them solves very specific traversal problems. So far so good. But now i am want to learn how to traverse this graph with [LIKQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/GraphEngine/tree/master/samples/freebase-likq).
LIKQ is a Language-Integrated Knowledge Query language. It allows users to query, search, and consume knowledge via graph traversal and lambda expressions in real-time.

### Question

What i want to do: Find all the shortest paths between *node A and C* and *node A and E*. Is this possible with LIKQ?

This is what i got so far:

```
 List<PathDescriptor> paths = KnowledgeGraph.StartFrom(start)
            .FollowEdge("OutEdges")
            .VisitNode(_ => Action.Continue)
            .FollowEdge("OutEdges")
            .VisitNode(_ => Action.Continue)
            .FollowEdge("OutEdges")
            .VisitNode(_ => Action.Return)
            .ToList();
```

I can traverse from *A - B - D - E*. But this is somehow an manual step to do. Is there any chance to let LIKQ decide how to start from node A and get two paths (to C and E) as a return?

Furthermore i would like to know if a BFS or a DFS could be translated to LIKQ?

[image: VSDebug]

Hope someone can bring some light into the dark (:
Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,
Phil

Comment: @Yadli,Can you help me with this question? [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250406/graphengine-likq-query-throw-system-nullreferenceexception)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250406/graphengine-likq-query-throw-system-nullreferenceexception

Answer (score 4):

Currently this is a bit tricky, the fanout search algorithm does not guarantee the order of emitted traversal steps, but shorter paths do get scheduled earlier practically. So if you put `Action.Continue & Action.Return` in every step, and make a global flag variable so when you hit the target, toggle that bit so every other path reading it could stop, then you will *likely* get the shortest path.